# Component not rendering nor providing an error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table in a component, which I render into another component however, when I render the component inside of another component, it is not appearing, and due to the complete lack of errors I can't even proceed. I've checked how I've imported etc and it seems correct. But perhaps someone can spot something I haven't. I'm very new to VueJs so apologies for the untrimmed code, I'm not 100% on what could be relevant yet.

File I'm Importing Into.vue

```
        <template>
      <div>
        <b-table
            :striped="striped"
            :bordered="false"
            :data="participants"
            detailed
            class="participant-table"
            :row-class="() => 'participant-row'"
        >
          <InternalTable></InternalTable>
    
          <b-table-column field="columnValue" v-slot="props2" class="attr-column">
            <b-table
                :bordered="false"
                class="attr-table"
                :striped="true"
                :data="props2.row.columnValues"
            >
              <b-table-column field="columnName" v-slot="itemProps">
                <SelectableAttribute
                    :attr-name="props2.row.fieldClass"
                    :attr-id="itemProps.row.id"
                    :model-id="itemProps.row.id"
                    model-name="NewParticipant"
                >
                  {{ itemProps.row.value }}
                </SelectableAttribute>
              </b-table-column>
            </b-table>
          </b-table-column>
        </b-table>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { snakeCase } from "snake-case";
    import InternalTable from './InternalTable'
    import SelectableAttribute from '../groups/SelectableAttribute'
    
    export default {
  props: {
    bordered: true,
    striped: true,
    participants: [
        {
        primaryAlias: '',
        primaryEmail: '',
        primaryAddress: '',
        primaryPhone: '',
      }
    ]
  },

      },


  components: {
    SelectableAttribute,
    InternalTable
  },

  methods: {
    tableDataToDataValueCells(participant) {
      const fields = [
        { fieldName: 'companyNames', fieldClass: 'CompanyName' },
        { fieldName: 'aliases', fieldClass: 'Alias' },
        { fieldName: 'addresses', fieldClass: 'Address' },
        { fieldName: 'phones', fieldClass: 'Phone' },
        { fieldName: 'emails', fieldClass: 'Email' },
        { fieldName: 'birthdates', fieldClass: 'Birthdate' },
        { fieldName: 'customerNumbers', fieldClass: 'CustomerNumber' },
        { fieldName: 'ibans', fieldClass: 'BankAccount' },
      ];
      let result = [];

      fields.forEach(field => {
        if (participant[field.fieldName].length > 0) {
          result.push({
            attributeName: field.fieldName,
            columnName: I18n.t(`ccenter.participant.table.${snakeCase(field.fieldName)}`),
            columnValues: participant[field.fieldName],
            fieldClass: field.fieldClass,
          })
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.table tbody tr.detail:last-child td {
  border-width: 1px !important;
}

.participant-table .participant-row td {
  word-break: break-word;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}

.cell-action {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
.cell-action .b-radio {
  margin: 0px;
}

.attr-table table thead {
  display: none;
}

.attr-table table td {
  border: none;
}

.attrs-detail-container table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.attrs-detail-container table thead {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

InternalTable.Vue

```
    <template>
  <b-table :data="participants" detailed class="participant-table" :row-class="() => 'participant-row'">
    <b-table-column field="primaryAlias" :label="t('participant.table.primary_alias')" v-slot="props">
      <template v-if="props.row.primaryAlias">{{ props.row.primaryAlias.value }}</template>
      <template v-else>-</template>
    </b-table-column>

    <b-table-column field="primaryEmail" :label="t('participant.table.primary_email')" v-slot="props">
      <template v-if="props.row.primaryEmail">{{ props.row.primaryEmail.value }}</template>
      <template v-else>-</template>
    </b-table-column>

    <b-table-column field="primaryAddress" :label="t('participant.table.primary_address')" v-slot="props">
      <template v-if="props.row.primaryAddress">{{ props.row.primaryAddress.value }}</template>
      <template v-else>-</template>
    </b-table-column>

    <b-table-column field="primaryPhone" :label="t('participant.table.primary_phone')" v-slot="props">
      <template v-if="props.row.primaryPhone">{{ props.row.primaryPhone.value }}</template>
      <template v-else>-</template>
    </b-table-column>

    <b-table-column v-slot="props" cell-class="cell-action">
      <slot v-bind="props.row">
      </slot>
    </b-table-column>

    <template slot="detail" slot-scope="props">
      <b-table class="attrs-detail-container" :data="tableDataToDataValueCells(props.row)" cell-class="with-bottom-border">
        <b-table-column field="columnName" v-slot="props">
          <b>{{ props.row.columnName }}</b>
        </b-table-column>
      </b-table>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</template>

<script>
import { snakeCase } from "snake-case"

export default {
  props: {
    participants: {
      type: Array,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    tableDataToDataValueCells(participant) {
      const fields = [
        { fieldName: 'companyNames', fieldClass: 'CompanyName' },
        { fieldName: 'aliases', fieldClass: 'Alias' },
        { fieldName: 'addresses', fieldClass: 'Address' },
        { fieldName: 'phones', fieldClass: 'Phone' },
        { fieldName: 'emails', fieldClass: 'Email' },
        { fieldName: 'birthdates', fieldClass: 'Birthdate' },
        { fieldName: 'customerNumbers', fieldClass: 'CustomerNumber' },
        { fieldName: 'ibans', fieldClass: 'BankAccount' },
      ];
      let result = [];

      fields.forEach(field => {
        if (participant[field.fieldName].length > 0) {
          result.push({
            attributeName: field.fieldName,
            columnName: I18n.t(`ccenter.participant.table.${snakeCase(field.fieldName)}`),
            columnValues: participant[field.fieldName],
            fieldClass: field.fieldClass,
          })
        }
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
  .table tbody tr.detail:last-child td {
    border-width: 1px !important;
  }

  .participant-table .participant-row td {
    word-break: break-word;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
  }

  .cell-action {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
  }
  .cell-action .b-radio {
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .attr-table table thead {
    display: none;
  }

  .attr-table table td {
    border: none;
  }

  .attrs-detail-container table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 !important;
  }

  .attrs-detail-container table thead {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you trying to use props in your `InternalTable.vue`, which you used like this:

```
props: {
   participants: {
      type: Array,
   }
}
```

In your `Into.vue`, you just call your component without providing these props. You should change:

```
<InternalTable></InternalTable>
```

to

```
<InternalTable :participants="participants"></InternalTable>
```

Looks like your `b-table` isn´t rendering because you didn´t provide data.

---

**EDIT: Your data needs to be filled first**

Currently, your array `participants` is empty, it just consists of:

```
participants: {
   type: Array,
   default: null,
}
```

In your `InternalTable.vue` you refer to `primaryAlias`, `primaryEmail`, `primaryAddress` and `primaryPhone` at your `b-table-column`´s. This data isn´t provided yet, thats why the table renders without data. You need to provide an array with a minimum structure of:

```
participants: [
   {
      primaryAlias: '',
      primaryEmail: '',
      primaryAddress: '',
      primaryPhone: ''
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, it then renders without data.

Comment: @cdln I don´t see that you get any data in `Into.vue` for `participants`. Is this the whole code or is there something missing?

Comment: @StephenSiebert Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. But then I receive the following "[Vue warn]: Invalid prop type: "[object Object]" is not a constructor"

Comment: @cdln In your `Into.vue` `participants: {...}` is an object, but in `InternalTable.vue` you want to receive `participants: {type: Array}` as an array. You need to change the type of your prop or the type of `participants`.

Comment: I've updated my example to show as it is now, yet no visible data, the data I want to see is only visible in my Vue Tools.

Comment: @cdln Where do you fill your data of `participants` in `Into.vue`? Because it is actual just an empty object.